# 3 TB hard drive suddenly no longer recognized

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

My 3TB Western Digital WD30EXRX hard drive that used to work perfectly fine, is suddenly no longer being recognized properly. It isn't mounted automatically anymore, the file manager does not recognize it at all and in gnome-disks it is shown as an empty hard drive with 802GB of free space.

What could possibly be a reason for this and what can I do to repair the disk/recover the data?

Comment: In order to better help you, could you please open a terminal and edit your question to include the output of the `lsblk` command.

Answer (score -2):

Your drive is most probably suffering from corrupt firmware and the drive will need to be set back to its native/default capacity.

[HDD Capacity Restore Tool](http://hddguru.com/software/2007.07.20-HDD-Capacity-Restore-Tool/) will be able to help you with that.

Comment: I checked the 'tool' and it only runs in windows platform `Operating System: MS Windows 2000/2003/XP`. How is this supposed to help in Ubuntu?

Comment: It is possible to run Windows programs in Ubuntu using Wine. For a step by step process check out: [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-Programs-in-Ubuntu)